# msbuild & wix - multiple installers?

Tags: msbuild, wix

I'm working with an application framework that has multiple products. It has a single installer and plugins are included/excluded based on build-server configuration.

I would like to change my build process so that multiple msi files are produced from a single build (one for each product, based on the framework). Is that possible ?

Comment: We solved this by using the msbuild task to build separate WiX projects from the "main" msbuild, which just compiled everything. Within the separate WiX projects we set up the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I was strugling the same problem.

I had 2 different builds from 1 wxs file, and for 4 configurations from 1 build. e.g. build=server\client,conf=debug\release,platf=x86\x64.

**My issue:** to cerate a solution with projects, numbered by the variable of build (in my case there was 2 projects, for server and for client separate). every project needs to be based on one wxs file, and build properties need to be different. I used the standard env variables on Configuration and Platform, and used my own variable Build. I've done in that way. If u need more biulds, create more projects, use more variables...

**P.S.** If u find the better way, plz contact me.